# Sails.JS will not lift without autoIncrement being set to true for my model's id attribute

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

Unfortunately this table uses `id` as a varchar(255) and there is no column used as an auto-incrementing id. For my purposes I cannot change that. The `id` is a string and there's no way around that for me.

```
module.exports = {

  tableName: 'report_config',
  attributes: {

    id: { type: 'string', autoIncrement: true },
    APP_NAME: {type: 'string' },
    REPORT_NAME: {type: 'string'},
    REPORT_DESCRIPTION: {type: 'string'},
    USERNAME: {type: 'string'},
    CONTACT_NAME: {type: 'string'},
  },

};
```

When I go to the route for this model (no controller or view has been defined yet, just the default controller file that is created) I am presented with 30 entries. I understand this is due to the blueprints feature which is pretty handy.

However, if I remove `autoIncrement` from `id` I get an error when trying to lift the application:

```
error: Could not tear down the ORM hook.  Error details: Error: Invalid data store identity. No data store exist with that identity.
```

I commented out the `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, and `id` attributes in `models.js` and I don't know where else this default would be set.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to make sure that id is set to `required: true`.